# Color Change in Area Chart

Tags: css, javafx

i have a Java-Class that extends the AreaChart. There i would like to implement a method that makes more or less something like this:

```
public void addNewColorToData(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, redColor, greenColor, blueColor);
```

-> The Function should get the parameters of the Data for the xCoordinate, yCoordinate and then for the RGB Value of the representes Line.

Is it possible to create with Inline-Styles a new Color for this ?

[image]

Here you can see a Sample. There are a lot of Color-Fills for the Area Chart!
Is it possible to add there some new colors?

I need to add a Inline Style stuff like this in CSS:

```
.default-color0.chart-series-area-fill { -fx-fill: #007Fc350; }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Do you want to create a Color based on three parameters (r,g,b)? What does this have to do with the data parameters? Where will be the color applied (fill, background, text,...)?

Comment: @JoséPereda The Color is needed to fill the Line with the Color. I added a Sample-Picture to the Question!

Comment: Ok, you were talking about data (each of the x,y points), instead of series...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23230027/3956070), to create an inline style based on r,g,b parameters (given these are integers from 0 to 255) you just need to override the `CHART_COLOR_1` (up to `CHART_COLOR_8`) value to modify the line color and `CHART_COLOR_1_TRANS_20` (up to `CHART_COLOR_8_TRANS_20`) to modify the area color:

```
private AreaChart<String, Number> areaChart;

private void changeColor(int redColor, int greenColor, int blueColor, double opacity){
    /* int redColor=0, greenColor=127, blueColor=195; 
       double opacity=0.4;
    */
    areaChart.setStyle("CHART_COLOR_1: rgb("+redColor+","+greenColor+","+blueColor+");" +
           "CHART_COLOR_1_TRANS_20: rgba("+redColor+","+greenColor+","+blueColor+");");
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm adding this short MVCE for the sake of clarity:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    AreaChart<String, Number> areaChart=new AreaChart<>(new CategoryAxis(),new NumberAxis());

    ObservableList<XYChart.Data<String,Integer>> xyList
            = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new XYChart.Data<>("P1", 30),
                    new XYChart.Data<>("P2", 40),
                    new XYChart.Data<>("P3", 30));
    XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series(xyList);
    areaChart.getData().addAll(series);

    Button button = new Button("Change style");
    button.setOnAction(e->{
        int redColor=0, greenColor=127, blueColor=195;
        double opacity=0.3;
        areaChart.setStyle("CHART_COLOR_1: rgb("+redColor+","+greenColor+","+blueColor+"); "
                + "CHART_COLOR_1_TRANS_20: rgba("+redColor+","+greenColor+","+blueColor+","+opacity+");");
    });

    VBox root = new VBox(5, button, areaChart);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);        
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

This would be the result:

[image: Styled chart]

Comment: This example does not work ... I try it, but it makes nothing

Comment: I try this solution also but it also does not work for me. Do you try it? The parameter opacity in the changeColor Method is never used...

Comment: Do you try this sample?

Comment: Sure I did. I have an `AreaChart`, added one series with random data, and then I change its style. Post some code so I can tell...

Comment: I took your complete code and put it in my code and it does not work

Comment: Wow, why can't this be documented in the JavaDoc somewhere? Thanks for helping me ;)