# JavaFX Coloring XYChart.Series

Tags: java, css, charts, javafx, styles

I am trying to style my JavaFX Area-Chart, but can't find any way to set color to specific series. I know, that I can style via CSS, but i want to do it in the code also.

How can i do that?
1.) How to set a color to Area-Chart with Inline Styles?

Thank you for your help.

@Jose:

I done it before like this, but it does not work for me!

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        final AreaChart<String, Number> areaChart = new AreaChart<>(new CategoryAxis(), new NumberAxis());

        ObservableList<XYChart.Data<String, Integer>> xyList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new XYChart.Data<>("P1", 30),
            new XYChart.Data<>("P2", 40),
            new XYChart.Data<>("P3", 30));
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series(xyList);
        areaChart.getData().addAll(series);

        Button button = new Button("Change style");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0)
            {
                int redColor = 0, greenColor = 127, blueColor = 195;
                double opacity = 0.3;
                areaChart.setStyle("CHART_COLOR_1: rgb(" + redColor + "," + greenColor + "," + blueColor + "); "
                    + "CHART_COLOR_1_TRANS_20: rgba(" + redColor + "," + greenColor + "," + blueColor + "," + opacity + ");");

            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(button, areaChart);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Comment: You have already an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26733056/3956070) for this.

Comment: @JoséPereda can you make again that sample file for me, without any Java8 Functions and so on? I can not use it becouse I'm using Java7! It also doesn't worked for me before. It would be very nice, if you can make there a complete class that handels it (Only Java7 Function-> Without Lambda Expressions and so on=

Comment: @JoséPereda I also only wanne change the Color for the Serie not for the Complete Chart.

Answer (score 3):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26733056/3956070) does not work in Java 7, because the default CSS stylesheet is Caspian, not Modena.

In Caspian these constants for the main color palette are not defined: `CHART_COLOR_1`, `CHART_COLOR_1_TRANS_20`,...

So if you want to apply inline styling one way to do it is by finding the series with a lookup and apply your styling to symbols, lines and/or areas, based on their CSS selectors. For instance:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    final AreaChart<String, Number> areaChart = new AreaChart<>(new CategoryAxis(), new NumberAxis());

    ObservableList<XYChart.Data<String, Integer>> xyList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new XYChart.Data<>("P1", 30),
        new XYChart.Data<>("P2", 40),
        new XYChart.Data<>("P3", 30));
    XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series(xyList);
    areaChart.getData().addAll(series);

    Scene scene = new Scene(areaChart, 400, 300);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    int redColor = 0, greenColor = 127, blueColor = 195;
    double opacity = 0.3;

    for(Node symbol : areaChart.lookupAll(".default-color0.chart-area-symbol")){
        symbol.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgb(" + redColor + "," + greenColor + "," + blueColor + "), white; ");
    }
    Node line = areaChart.lookup(".default-color0.chart-series-area-line");
    line.setStyle("-fx-stroke: rgb(" + redColor + "," + greenColor + "," + blueColor + "); ");
    Node area = areaChart.lookup(".default-color0.chart-series-area-fill");
    area.setStyle("-fx-fill: rgba(" + redColor + "," + greenColor + "," + blueColor + "," + opacity + "); ");
}
```

**EDIT**

The above solution will work up to 8 series.

For any number of series this other approach will work too:

```
    int numSeries=10;
    final int[] redColor = new int[numSeries];
    Arrays.fill(redColor, 0);
    final int[] greenColor =new int[numSeries]; 
    Arrays.fill(greenColor, 127);
    final int[] blueColor = new int[numSeries];
    Arrays.fill(blueColor, 195);
    double opacity = 0.3;


    for(int i=0; i<numSeries; i++){
        for(Node n : areaChart.lookupAll(".series"+i)){
            n.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgb(" + redColor[i] + "," + greenColor[i] + "," + blueColor[i] + "), white; "
                    + "-fx-stroke: rgb(" + redColor[i] + "," + greenColor[i] + "," + blueColor[i] + "); "
                    + "-fx-fill: rgba(" + redColor[i] + "," + greenColor[i] + "," + blueColor[i] + "," + opacity + "); ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think same solution :)

Comment: @Jose is it only possible to Style 8 "Default-Colors"? Becouse when im trying it with the Value 10 i get a nullpointer

Comment: Edited my answer with a solution for any number of series.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
chart-series-area-line series<i> default-color<j>
```

Where  is the index of the series and  is the series’ color index

as specificated in css reference [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#areachart) the same you can use with setStyle function of your areaChart

you can use this:

```
Node line = areaChart.lookup(".default-color0.chart-series-area-line");
line.setStyle("-fx-stroke: rgb(" + redColor + "," + greenColor + "," + blueColor + "); ");
```

Comment: Can you describe it a little bit more`?