# Change fill color of JavaFX Charts

Tags: java, javafx

I have successfully outputted a line chart using JavaFX. I would like to know how can I change the fill color (the orange) to make it transparent dynamically (possibly without the use of CSS).

This is the code I have till now;

```
@Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("ANN");
    //defining the axes
    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    xAxis.setLabel("Epochs");
    yAxis.setLabel("% of Bad Facts");
    //creating the chart
    final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart = 
            new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);

    lineChart.setTitle("Bad Facts vs Epochs");


    //defining a series
    XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();

    series.setName("BadFacts/Epoch");

    for (int k=0; k<Epochs.length; k++) {
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(Epochs[k], BadFacts[k]));
    }

    Scene scene  = new Scene(lineChart,1500,1100);
    lineChart.getData().add(series);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Can anyone hint anything please? Thanks! [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420115/javafx-coloring-xychart-series).

Comment: I think I'm confused now. the white dots in the middle of the area ... are those points? or is it filled? because I just want a thin line passing through the points... Thanks for your help!

Comment: It seems your chart contains a huge amount of data. The orange circles are the points, styled with `chart-area-symbol`. Try to add just a few values to the chart first, and then proceed to style it.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the circle symbol? I mean .. I'll just have the line left?  Because I'm actually thinking that the orange circles are like being 'dragged' from the axis all the way to the left...

Comment: As I said before, try to plot just a few points to see how they are plotted on the chart. Then update your question if you still need help styling the chart.

Comment: Solved ! thx  @José Pereda for your help ! I was adding the points at the wrong time ... no problem with the chart code!