# Change chart color based on ColorPicker input

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I would like to change line color based on ColorPicker input during runtime.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.AreaChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application
{
    private static final int MAX_DATA_POINTS = 50;

    private Series series;
    private int xSeriesData = 0;
    private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Number> dataQ = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    private ExecutorService executor;
    private AddToQueue addToQueue;
    private Timeline timeline2;
    private NumberAxis xAxis;
    private NumberAxis yAxis;
    private AreaChart<Number, Number> sc;

    private void init(Stage primaryStage)
    {

        xAxis = new NumberAxis(0, MAX_DATA_POINTS, MAX_DATA_POINTS / 10);
        xAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false);
        xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);

        yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        yAxis.setAutoRanging(true);

        sc = new AreaChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

        sc.setAnimated(false);
        sc.setId("liveAreaChart");
        sc.setTitle("Animated Area Chart");

        //-- Chart Series
        series = new AreaChart.Series<Number, Number>();
        series.setName("Area Chart Series");
        sc.getData().add(series);

        final ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker();

        colorPicker.setOnAction(new EventHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event t)
            {
                changeColor(colorPicker.getValue().getRed(), colorPicker.getValue().getGreen(), colorPicker.getValue().getBlue(), colorPicker.getValue().getOpacity());
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(5, colorPicker, sc);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    }

    private void changeColor(double redColor, double greenColor, double blueColor, double opacity)
    {
        /* int redColor=0, greenColor=127, blueColor=195;
         double opacity=0.4;
         */
        sc.setStyle("CHART_COLOR_1: rgb(" + redColor + "," + greenColor + "," + blueColor + ");"
            + "CHART_COLOR_1_TRANS_20: rgba(" + redColor + "," + greenColor + "," + blueColor + ");");
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        init(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();

        //-- Prepare Executor Services
        //-- Prepare Executor Services
        executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new ThreadFactory()
        {
            @Override
            public Thread newThread(Runnable r)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(r);
                thread.setDaemon(true);
                return thread;
            }
        });
        addToQueue = new AddToQueue();
        executor.execute(addToQueue);
        //-- Prepare Timeline
        prepareTimeline();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    private class AddToQueue implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                // add a item of random data to queue
                dataQ.add(Math.random());
                Thread.sleep(50);
                executor.execute(this);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(MainApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    //-- Timeline gets called in the JavaFX Main thread
    private void prepareTimeline()
    {
        // Every frame to take any data from queue and add to chart
        new AnimationTimer()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now)
            {
                addDataToSeries();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void addDataToSeries()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        { //-- add 20 numbers to the plot+
            if (dataQ.isEmpty())
                break;
            series.getData().add(new AreaChart.Data(xSeriesData++, dataQ.remove()));
        }
        // remove points to keep us at no more than MAX_DATA_POINTS
        if (series.getData().size() > MAX_DATA_POINTS)
        {
            series.getData().remove(0, series.getData().size() - MAX_DATA_POINTS);
        }
        // update
        xAxis.setLowerBound(xSeriesData - MAX_DATA_POINTS);
        xAxis.setUpperBound(xSeriesData - 1);
    }
}
```

The part which is most unknown to me is how I can get the color of the line during runtime?

Can you help me to implement this, please?

It will be great if I can chose the color from Context menu.

Update: after I select color the diagram is always black.

Comment: To change color see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731434/color-change-in-area-chart. To get color from colorpicker see https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/color-picker.htm

Comment: @UlukBiy I updated the code but now when I select color from the ColorPicker the LineChart is always black. Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the RGB value ranges from 0.0 - 0.1 to 0 - 255:

```
private void changeColor( double redColor, double greenColor, double blueColor, double opacity )
{
    int r = ( int ) Math.round( redColor * 255.0 );
    int g = ( int ) Math.round( greenColor * 255.0 );
    int b = ( int ) Math.round( blueColor * 255.0 );

    sc.setStyle( "CHART_COLOR_1: rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ");"
            + "CHART_COLOR_1_TRANS_20: rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + "," + 0.2 + ");" );
}
```

You may also set the initial default color of `ColorPicker` with the one defined in modena.css for `CHART_COLOR_1`:

```
final ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker( Color.web( "#f3622d" ) );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do you know how I can set the default color of the Colorpicker to be the same as the LineChart when the application starts?

Comment: I have defined the LineChart custom color in css file. How I can load the color from the LineChart?

Comment: @PeterPenzov, there is no linechart in both question and answer. Please first search the site for similar questions asked before. If you will not find then ask a new question.

Comment: My mistake I mean AreaChart

Comment: @PeterPenzov replace the "#f3622d" in the asnwer with your custom color.